# explanation of extraneous attributes example

Tags: database-design

I want to how to find extraneous attributes, though I read many articles I couldn't understand them. Many of them gives definition of the extraneous attributes. 
I found 2 examples from the book Database system concepts by Abraham Silberschatz,Henry F. Korth,S. Sudarshan.

1. FD F=(AB -> C , A -> C)
    extraneous attribute = B
2. FD F=(AB -> CD , A -> C )
    extraneous attribute = C

But I couldn't understand these 2 also because they didn't give any explanations. Can anybody explain how to find extraneous attributes?

Answer (score 0):

if A can identify C, then if you make a new key as composite key of A and B, it will all be able to identify C, but you can identify C without the help of B also so, that b is extraneous attribute.

Comment: Yea, 1st one is okay, but the problem is the second one. I can't understand the second one because we lost the A->C relationship when removing C as extraneous attribute.

Answer (score 0):

for 1st:
if A can identify C, then if you make a new key as composite key of A and B, it will all be able to identify C, but you can identify C without the help of B also so, that b is extraneous attribute.

for 2nd:
as per armstrong's decomposition rule

Ab->cd will decompose to AB->C AND AB->D
so now to can identify both c and D using a key of AB only, 
that make C an Extronious attribute in A->C and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Already Explained in other answer
2)A->C which implies C can be derived from A.
AB->CD can be decomposed to AB->C and AB->D.
But here we don't need AB to derive C because it can be derived from A. Hence redundant

Answer (score 0):

## 1  from the second dependency,we can see that C can be determined by A. So in the first dependency AB->C, B is extraneous.

## 2  From the second dependency A->C, we can see that C can be detrained by A,which means we don't really need Axxx->C, but we need AB to determine D. So in this case C is extra.